# Inserción dinámica en un arreglo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, validación, objeto

Buenos tardes tengo un problema al tratar de insertar un valor dinámico en una propiedad de un arreglo.
cada objeto tiene una propiedad que define el tipo de dato de cada objeto ejemplo: NUMBER, STRING.
y tengo una propiedad llamada campoDb en el cual debo darle un índice dinámico a esa propiedad por ejemplo:

en el bucle de abajo se crea 8 objetos correctamente, los 4 primeros objetos el campoDb esta correcto pero los siguientes 4 objetos están mal.

```
  0  {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 34},    
  1 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING1", valor: "vcd"},   
  2 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING2", valor: "abc"},    
  3 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 12}
  // hasta el objeto 4 esta correcto.
  4 {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER3", valor: 33},    
  5 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING3", valor: "sds"},   
  6 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING4", valor: "ffd"},    
  7 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER4", valor: 3}
```

ya que el 5to elemento es similar al 1ro solo que cambia el contenido de la propiedad valor, lo que deseo hacer es que todo objeto que tenga el mismo valor de la propiedad nombre adquiera automáticamente el valor de la propiedad campoDb. el arreglo deberia quedar así:

```
 0 {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 34},    
  1 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING1", valor: "vcd"},   
  2 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING2", valor: "abc"},    
  3 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 12}
  // hasta el objeto 4 esta correcto.
  4 {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 33},    
  5 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING1", valor: "sds"},   
  6 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING2", valor: "ffd"},    
  7 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER2", valor: 3}
```

```js
let columnas = [];

//Arreglo de columnas tipo de dato
let columnaServicio = [
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 1,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "ORDEN",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 2,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "CONTRAPARTIDA",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 3,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "NOMBRE",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7 
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 4,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "VALOR ENV.",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    }
    ]

//Arreglo de información
let val = [
           {
              "Contrapartida": "llgfhfg",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
              "Forma pago:": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 10645124,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 1,
              "Valor env.": 4.22
          },
          {
              "Contrapartida": "sdsdsd",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 334232,
              "Forma pago": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 33434,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 2,
              "Valor env.": 444
          }
                ]
         numbersCount = 0 // CONTADOR DE NUMBERS
         stringCount = 0  // CONTADOR DE STRING
     //inicio de los bucles    
    for(let k = 0; k < val.length; k++){
       for(let y = 0; y < columnaServicio.length; y++){
           columnas.push({
           "nombre": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE,
           "tipo": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO,
           "fila": k + 1,
           "campoDb":  columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO + ( (columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO == 'STRING' ? ++stringCount : ++numbersCount) ),
                });  
                   }
                    }
 console.log("columnas: ", columnas)
```

lo que necesito es que saber como podría corregir este error o que opción podría implementar para realizar lo que necesito

Comment: Esta edición cambia completamente el planteamiento de la pregunta original, resultando en pérdida de tiempo para ti y para quienes intentaron ayudarte. Por eso es importante [elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) desde el principio, incluyendo toda la información necesaria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno una posible solucion puede ser esta, agregas un contador para cada tipo y con una pequeña condicion puedes elegir a cual vas a incrementar y colocar

```js
let columnas = [];

//Arreglo de columnas tipo de dato
let columnaServicio = [
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 1,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "ORDEN",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 2,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "CONTRAPARTIDA",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 3,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "NOMBRE",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7 
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 4,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "VALOR ENV.",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    }
    ]

//Arreglo de información
let val = [
           {
              "Contrapartida": "llgfhfg",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
              "Forma pago:": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 10645124,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 1,
              "Valor env.": 4.22
          },
          {
              "Contrapartida": "sdsdsd",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 334232,
              "Forma pago": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 33434,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 2,
              "Valor env.": 444
          }
                ]
         
     
     //inicio de los bucles    
    for(let k = 0; k < val.length; k++){
       numbersCount = 0 // CONTADOR DE NUMBERS
       stringCount = 0  // CONTADOR DE STRING
       for(let y = 0; y < columnaServicio.length; y++){
           columnas.push({
           "nombre": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE,
           "tipo": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO,
           "fila": k + 1,
           "campoDb":  columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO + ((columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO == 'STRING' ? ++stringCount : ++numbersCount)),
                });  
                   }
                    }
 console.log("columnas: ", columnas)
```

Comment: amigo disculpa, tu solución funcionó, pero ahora tengo otro problema, ya edité la pregunta con el nuevo problema, ojala puedas ayudarme

Comment: hola @KennyCruz, segun tu nueva pregunta. controlando el scope de las variables de incremento es posible hacer lo que quieres, te edito la respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias, te pasaste usando el condicional ternario, gracias x la ayuda, saludos

Answer (score 3):

La mejor manera para solventar este escenario sería manejarlo por medio de una condicional, por ejemplo derivado de tu código aplique la siguiente condición en los bucles.

```
for(let k = 0; k < val.length; k++){
   let x = k + 1;
   for(let y = 0; y < columnaServicio.length; y++){         
       columnas.push({
       "nombre": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE,
       "tipo": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO,
       "fila": x,
       "campoDb":  columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO + x,
    });  
    if(y % 2 != 0)
       x = x+1;
    }
 }; console.log("columnas: ", columnas);
```

Y obtuve el resultado que necesitas

```
0: {nombre: "ORDEN", tipo: "NUMBER", fila: 1, campoDb: "NUMBER1"}
1: {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", tipo: "STRING", fila: 1, campoDb: "STRING1"}
2: {nombre: "NOMBRE", tipo: "STRING", fila: 2, campoDb: "STRING2"}
3: {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", tipo: "NUMBER", fila: 2, campoDb: "NUMBER2"}
```

Comment: hola gracias por responder, edité la pregunta, ojala puedas ayudarme a encontrar la solucion

Comment: Hola Kenny, no entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer, pero según entiendo, se resolvería poniendo unas cuantas condiciones más que dependan de los datos del objeto al que se le asignará el campoDb.